# Git tells me that file has changed when I simply save a file

Tags: git, atom-editor

Even though I did not change anything, Git tells me that file has changed whenever I save a file.

I cloned a repo, opened a random file, and hit save. here is what `git diff` shows me.

````
     1. `{{pathFor contextObject queryKey=queryValue hash=anchorTag}}`
     or
     2. ```
-        {{#with contextObject}}
+        {{#with contextObject}}
           {{pathFor queryKey=queryValue hash=anchorTag}}
         {{/with}}
        ```
````

But the line deleted and the line added are the same. This happens in multiple lines. Any ideas about why, and how to stop this?

**Update**

When I do `git diff -R`, I see a trailing whitespace:

```
-        {{#with contextObject}}
+        {{#with contextObject}}[trailing whitespace]
```

When I try to remove the whitespace manually, it is not there. Also, I have turned on `Remove Trailing Whitespace` option in Atom.

[image: atom setting]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are there changes you can't see? Line endings? Trailing blanks? Try `git diff | cat -A` (if you're on a Unix-like system).

Comment: what happens if you uncheck the first and last options in Atom (which sound intrusive and may change the file), and check the second and third options (which sound passive and won't change the file)?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your editor automatically removes whitespace, or that it changes the type of newline or tabs to spaces. What happens when you diff using the `diff` command?

Comment: I checked using `git diff -R`, and the problem turns out that my editor is not removing whitespaces. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called the 'whitespace' package in Atom, disable it. The issue should go away.